# is adding a table for video, image, and audio a good job for normalizing the database or not

Tags: django, database, orm, database-schema

I have an app that has a lot of videos, audios, and images about persons, events, diaries and so on. is it a good practice to having a distinct table for all types of multimedia to query over them and their information and detail fields or there is another good way to handle this mission. evenly, if this is a good solution for normalizing the database, or not?

I explored into the net but did not see any complete description about if there is a way to distinct multimedia from tables and just pointing to them through using queries and joining tables, or this is the common way that professional developers do!